# How does a compiler use T::operator< in std::set when the template parameter asks for std::less<T>?

Tags: c++

When you create a `std::set`, one of the template parameters is `class Compare`, which defaults to `std::less<T>`.

Now, even if you don't give a specialization of `std::less<T>`, defining `T::operator<` is good enough for C++ to "figure it out". But C++ isn't figuring anything out, a compiler is.

And the compiler is going through a series of what I'm sure are simple steps. What are those steps?

Comment: `But C++ isn't figuring anything out, a compiler is.` To be fair, C++ dictates what the compiler does (to an extent. It gives boundaries that the compiler must follow. In rare cases it will let the compiler choose what to do, but this doesn't seem to be one of those cases).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard library is defined such that `std::less<T>` will use `operator<` unless otherwise specialized. So if you don't provide a specialization, if the type supports `<` then it will work out.

From [`std::less<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) :

> Function object for performing comparisons. Unless specialized, invokes `operator<` on type `T`.

And for `std::less<T>::operator()` :

> Possible implementation :

```
constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const
{
    return lhs < rhs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the compiler-defined specialization of [std::less<void>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void).

As you can see, it simply *returns the result of lhs < rhs*.

As for how the compiler knows to bind `std::less<void>` instead of `std::less<T>`, that's because no specialization of `std::less<T>` has been explicitly written. So when you ask for it, it must be automatically generated.

So why does the compiler find `std::less<void>` instead of `std::less<>`? That's because when you pass no template parameter to `std::less` you get `std::less<void>`.

Comment: `std::less<T>` definitely "exists", in that that specialization is automatically generated when you ask for it. `std::less` is simply declared `template<typename T = void> struct less;`, so if you ask for `std::less<>` without giving `T` then you get `T = void` by default. The only magic is if `T` is a pointer type.

Comment: I'm not sure why you introduced `void` into this.

Comment: That is what I understand from what I just learned from google. Please! I would love if you were to give me a better answer.

Comment: the `std::less<void>` implementation isn't relevant, `std::set<T>` defaults to `std::less<T>`

Comment: @AriSweedler The only reason `void` is mentioned in `std::less<T>` is because since C++14 the template argument `T` defaults to `void`. So `std::less<>` is `std::less<void>`. But `std::set<T>` uses `std::less<T>` so the default template argument never comes into play in this context.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see (@ sentences 1 & 2). And @ sentence 3, I think I understand... Even though I thought I didn't implement `std::less<MyClass>`, by defining `MyClass::operator<` I am actually defining the missing piece in the std library that allows the generic template `std::less<T>` to specialize `MyClass`.

Comment: @AriSweedler Yes. If you provide `MyClass::operator<` then `std::less<MyClass>` can use the generic implementation of `std::less<T>` because that implementation just requires that there exists an `operator<` that uses `T`. Note that you can also provide the free function `bool operator<(const MyClass &, const MyClass &)` instead and it would also work.